# OnPlayerDeathEvent does not work

Tags: java, bukkit

I have been trying to make a gun game plugin but I can't get the on player death event to work. The plugin loads just fine but when I kill another player nothing happens.

```
package me.GunGame;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

  @
  Override
  public void onEnable() {
    getLogger().info("Gun Game Enabled");
  }@
  Override
  public void onDisable() {
    getLogger().info("Gun Game Disabled");
  }

  @
  EventHandler
  public void OnPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getEntity();
    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You have died!");
    Player k = p.getKiller();
    k.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You killed " + p.getDisplayName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your plugin for receiving the events. Use `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents` to register. See [Event API Reference](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference#Registering_Events) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to the onEnable()

You didn't register your event.

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    getLogger().info("Gun Game Enabled");
}
```

Simple mistake, people downvoted because if you read over your code, you would have seen that. Also it mentions it multiple times on the wiki.